# Networkx graph from nested dict containing lists

Tags: python, graph, networkx

**Question**

Given the following dict as input:

```
{'apple': [{'colours': ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, {'type': ['granny smith']}, {'price': ['0.10']}]}
```

How do I create a graph, with the following edges, using networkx:

[image]

**What have I tried?**

I can create a simple graph but not containing all the edges:

```
g = nx.Graph(d["apple"][0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly straightforward with a recursive function, as your data structure always has a key mapping to a list, and each item in the list is either another dictionary (on which you can recurse) or a leaf node.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph

def parse(data):
    edges = []
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, items in data.items():
            for item in items:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    edges.extend([(key, subitem) for subitem in item])
                    edges.extend(parse(item))
                else:
                    edges.append((key, item))
    return edges


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sample_data = {'apple': [{'colours': ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, {'type': ['granny smith']}, {'price': ['0.10']}]}
    edges = parse(sample_data)
    g = nx.from_edgelist(edges, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    Graph(g, node_layout='dot', node_labels=True, node_label_fontdict=dict(size=20),
          edge_color='black', edge_alpha=1., edge_width=0.1, node_edge_width=0.)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for introducing me to netgraph